# How to get the function body out of a string containing a function?

Tags: php, tokenize

Heres the string:

```
<?php
$string = '//ps: this placeholder text to demonstrate issues..

function go($url) {
header("Location: {$url}");
exit();
}

function some() {

/* this is the function body */

$result = mysql_query("SELECT something FROM sometable");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

//something...
}

return "something";

/* this is the function body */

}

function fetch2($result) {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

//something...
}

return "something";

}';
?>
```

I've tried regex it works on some occasions and other occasions it doesn't (if there are braces within the function body I can't control the greedyness).

This is what I tried:

```
preg_match('#function some\(\)\s*{(.+?)}#s', $string, $matches);

echo $match[1];
```

However, this does not give me the complete function body due to the set of braces before the closing brace interfering with the matching.

My question (ellaborated): How can I get the function body more reliably (without it being troublesome when theirs braces before the closing brace)? Someone suggested to use `token_get_all()` but I have no clue how to use it or what I should use it for.

Comment: PHP is a bit complex for single regexs to handle, it'll need parsing.

Comment: @Orbling Yes I did some research and appears so token_get_all() would be a better way of doing this - but I'm not entirally sure.

Comment: You might find it easier to use [`parsekit_compile_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parsekit-compile-string.php) than [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) - though neither have a reversal.

Comment: Maybe `preg_split` based on `}function(...){` then find the elements left. _[removed regex, it was buggy]_

Comment: @Orbling and @Brad Christie I appreciate the comments suggesting possible methods, but would it be possible to post an answer to realise your suggestions?

Comment: It is possible with a regex, but not trivial... Haven't tried this but it looks like it may do the job : http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1135

Comment: @Damp: You'll find there are many cases that'll break almost any regex for this sort of thing.  I'm a major regex advocate against the nay sayers, but this I would not try.

Comment: @Damp thats more BBCode focused - I'll see if I can modify it to do the job.

Comment: @newbtophp: Why do you need the function bodies from this string?  There maybe a better approach to solve your issue.

Comment: How about a counter that will increment the counter when the opening brace is found and decrement the counter when the closing brace is found? In that case, when the next 0 value in the counter occurs, that is the function block.

Comment: @Neigyl Noval Would you mind posting some code for better understanding?

Comment: What if you escape the { in the regex? `function some\(\) \{(.+?)\}`

Comment: I am not actually convinced of my idea because it is somehow longer than using regex because I thought you need some parsing algorithms. This is my idea: $cnt = 0; for(loop each char in $string using index $i) { if($str[$i] == '{') ++$cnt; else if($str[$i] == '}') { --cnt; } ... ... if($cnt == 0) { function block str } }

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$fragments = preg_split('/([\{\}])/', $string,0,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$functions = array();
$currentfunctionbody = '';
$currentnesting = 0;
$functionname = '';

for($i = 0; $i<count($fragments); $i++) {

    $str = $fragments[$i];

    /* New function ? */
    preg_match("!function (.*?)\\(!", $str, $matches);
    if(count($matches) > 0) {
        $functionname = $matches[1]; }
    /* Append to function body and deal with nesting */
    else {
        if(substr($str, 0,1) == '{') { 
            $currentnesting++; }
        else if(substr($str, -1,1) == '}') { 
            $currentnesting--; }
        $currentfunctionbody.=$str;
    }

    /* Close function */
    if($currentfunctionbody != '' && $currentnesting == 0)
    {
        $functions[$functionname] = trim($currentfunctionbody,"{}");
        $currentfunctionbody = '';
        $functionname = ''; 
    }


}
print_r($functions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative solution that reads directly from a file:

```
$array = get_function_body('source.php', 'some');
print_r($array['body']);

function get_function_body($sourceFile, $functionName) {
    $fd = fopen($sourceFile, "r");
    while (!feof($fd)) {
        $content = fgets($fd);
        if ($content == "") { 
            continue;
        }
        if (isset($ret['args'])) {
            if ($content == "//EOF")
            break;
            if (preg_match('/^\s*function\s+/', $content)) {
                // EOFunction?
                break;
            }
            $ret['body'] .= $content;
            continue;
        }
        if (preg_match('/^\s*function\s+(.*)\s*\((.*)\)\s*\{\s*$/', $content, $resx)) {
            if ($resx[1] == $functionName) {
                $ret['args'] = $resx[2];
                $ret['body'] = "";
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($fd);
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the swift response, would you mind showing how it would work with a $string instead of a filename?

Answer (score 0):

Just happened today to have a need for a tool to examine the source code of
PHP functions on-the-fly, and not really seeing anything interesting around ,
I tossed together the class pasted down below that uses some of PHP's reflection classes.

It will not only give you the source code of the PHP function , on-the-fly,
but it will also give you detailed information on the function's parameters (when available)

So if the function you were interrogating was something like this....

```
function nearby($lat=41.1663079,$lng=-113.8584736,$distance=150)
    {
    ....
    ....
    }
```

... The class would aside from the function's source , give you detailed
field information like this...

```
Array(  [lat] => Array(     [position]  => 0
                [name]      => lat
                [type]      => string
                [default]   => 41.1663079
                [optional]  => 1
                [byreference]   => 0    )
    [lng] => Array(     [position]  => 1
                [name]      => lng
                [type]      => string
                [default]   => -113.8584736
                [optional]  => 1
                [byreference]   => 0    )
    [distance] => Array(    [position]  => 2
                [name]      => distance
                [type]      => string
                [default]   => 150
                [optional]  => 1
                [byreference]   => 0    )   )
```

PHP's reflection classes are not well documented ,(often no documentation),
but there was enough that with a little fidgeting today, same  allowed the creation 
of the PHP "func_def" class below.

I built it to support a larger effort that lets me securely call PHP functions in real time from Javascript with type checking and such.

Enjoy!

EXAMPLE:

```
$function_inspector =new func_def('whatever_function_name');

print "the function's source code is \n\n"
.$function_inspector->func_get_code() ;

print "the function's argument details are ".print_r($function_inspector->func_get_args());


/*
**
**  The cool func_def class
**  Scribbled up by :Dr. Clue
**
*/

class   func_def    extends ReflectionFunction
    {//http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunctionabstract.php
    protected   $sz_fun_name    =NULL   ;
    protected   $bExists    =FALSE  ;
    function    __construct($func_name)
        {
        $this->sz_func_name=$func_name;
        if(!function_exists($func_name))return;
        try         {parent::__construct($func_name);   $this->bExists=TRUE;}
        catch(Exception $e) {$this->bExists=FALSE;      return;     }
        }   //  End Functon __constructor
    function    function_valid()        {       return $this->bExists==TRUE;        }
    function    func_get_code()
        {   //  Returns Function's source code
        if(!$this->bExists){return "/* function does not exist */";}
        $line_start     =$this->getStartLine() - 1;
        $line_end       =$this->getEndLine();
        $line_count     =$line_end - $line_start;
        $line_array     =file($this->getFileName());
        return      implode("", array_slice($line_array,$line_start,$line_count));
        }   //  End Function
    function    func_get_args()
        {   //  Returns a fairly detailed descript of function arguments
        $aParamerters=Array();
        if(!$this->bExists)return $aParamerters;
        foreach($Params=$this->getParameters() as $k=>$v)
            {
            $item= Array();
            $s_export=array_pop($a=(array)$v->export($this->getName(),$v->getName(),TRUE)   );
            preg_match('/[^#]+[#]([0-9]+)/',$s_export,$m,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
            $item["position"]=$m[1][0];$item["name" ]=$v->getName();$item["default" ]=$item["type"  ]=NULL;
            if(($item["optional"]=intVal($v->isOptional()) )==1)
                if(preg_match('/[^[]+[^=]+=([^\]]+)/',$s_export,$m,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
                {$item["default"]=($ev=trim($m[1][0]));$ev=("\$a=$ev;");eval($ev);$item["type"]=gettype($ev);}
            if($item["type" ]==NULL)
                if(preg_match('/[^[]+[\[][^>]+[> ]+([^&$]+)/',$s_export,$m,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))$item["type"]=($ev=trim($m[1][0]));
            $item["byreference"]=intVal(strpos($s_export,'&$')!==FALSE);
            $aParamerters[$v->getName()]=$item;
            }
        return  $aParamerters;
        }
    function    func_num_args()     {if(!$this->bExists)return FALSE;return $this->getNumberOfParameters()  ;}
    function    func_num_args_required(){if(!$this->bExists)return FALSE;return $this->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();}
    }   //  End Class
```